# Not getting friends list from Facebook in our Unity3D Android app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm using code taken directly from Facebook's FriendSmash game, Unity3D version. We've explicitly requested user_friends permission.

I have several Facebook test accounts which I've been trying to use. All accounts are friends with each other.

Login works fine. I can get the users name and some other basic information. We can share our app and invite people using Facebook.

```
string queryString = "/me/friends?fields=id,first_name,picture.width(128).height(128)&limit=100";
    FB.API(queryString, HttpMethod.GET, GetFriendsCallback);
```

I did notice that our app doesn't show up in Facebook, under our user profiles app list.

I tried using the following query in the graph explorer and it doesn't return any friends either.

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I double checked the user accounts to make sure they can all sign into Facebook and invite people and they all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is because you can see only the friends that *have logged in with your application and allowed the `user_friends` permission*.

From [Facebook's API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends#read) about `/user/friends`:

> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the `user_friends` permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

So make sure that

1. You have logged in to your app with `user_friends` permission
2. A friend in your friend list has logged in to your app with `user_friends` permission

Then you should be able to see that friend in `/me/friends` endpoint.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, each person has logged in with facebook, was able to invite people and are all friends with each other. I also double verified that they have user_friends permission.

Comment: @user1459723 Are the "test accounts" you mentioned created with 1) Facebook Developer Console (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOURAPPID/roles/test-users/), or are they 2) "real" Facebook users you have created from facebook.com front page?

Comment: They're real accounts. I also have them set as test account for the app in the developer console.

Comment: @ user1459723 Sounds really strange. Can you test how things look with Grap API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/YOUR_APP_ID?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.5) if you test with some of your test user's access token?

Comment: I did test with the explorer as well. It returns an empty list with the total number of friends so it doesn't return any of the friends using the app.
This is very strange since everything else seems to be working fine.

Comment: @user1459723 I'd double (triple?) check that you have a correct app id set when you're making requests and log in. You should also check the test users' access tokens with the [access token debigger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/), just to double-check that your `app id` and `scope` are correct in the tokens. The code you provided is working fine in my tests, so the problem must exist somewhere else. Also make sure that you're using 2.x API to make the requests. That's about all the hints I can give to debug this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll recheck and test everything. There must be something I'm missing somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

So after going over every setting over and over again I figured I would start from the beginning.
I reconfigured all my settings and verified the Android Key Hashes. It turned out the hash had I and l. Due to the font, it looks like we entered some I's for lower case L's.
After using keytool to get the release key and added it to the Android key hashes and BAM! just like that it worked.
What remains strange is that prior to adding this other key, the players were able invite players and share the game. They could even post to their timeline.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.